# Translate return codes SQLITE_OK, ..., SQLITE_DONE to an enum class in C++ (without ask clients to include the C header)

Tags: c++, sqlite, class, enums, forward-declaration

I have a `persistence_manager_t` class which hides the available implementations to the users.
One implementation is by using `SQLite` whom return codes are C pre-processing defines as

```
#define SQLITE_OK           0   /* Successful result */
```

Now I'm trying to create an enum class without writing by hand return code, i.e.

```
// persistence_manager_t.cpp
#include <sqlite3.h>
enum class persistence_manager_status {
    STATUS_OK = SQLITE_OK, STATUS_ROW = SQLITE_ROW, STATUS_DONE = SQLITE_DONE
};
```

but as class users try to

```
auto rc = context->persistence->open(db_name);
if(rc != persistence_manager_status::STATUS_OK) {
    // TODO: gestione errori
}
```

it turns out that the enum class should be defined in the header and so I either have to include `sqlite3.h` in the public header `persistence_manager.h` or class users should include `sqlite3.h` by themself in their implementation (very weird as they need to install sqlite-dev).

As per C++17, is there such a thing as forward declaration or similar for enum class implementation also? How can we use it?

Comment: Does the status values in sqlite3.h change frequently?  If not, you could use the values in your enum class, and add a comment saying the values are copied verbatim out of sqlite3.h and not to change them.  In the persistence_manager_t.cpp, you could add some static_assert to make sure the enum values match the sqlite3.h values, to catch if someone messed with the values.

Comment: That's exactly what I've done. But, this solution requires a mapping to the SQLITE_**KEY** in the implementations, too. So decoupling here seems to be utopia.

Comment: It is worth making sure your persistence_manager doesn't have a "leaky abstraction", where the client code of persistence_manager has to be aware of SQLite-isms.  That way, when you replace SQLite with DB2 or Oracle or Azure or AWS or GCP or MySQL or PostgreSQL or MongoDB or LiteDB or Firebase or JSON or YAML or BSON or XML... you're client code won't have to also be refactored.  Unfortunately, this tends to be hard until you've had to rework the code a couple times, to figure out the appropriate abstraction barrier.

Comment: `persistence_manager` currently has leaky abstraction because of class' users must have sqlite-dev installed in their dev machine. If the mapping function does the trick, everything will work seamlessly and abstraction-complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can forward declare an `enum class`, but you seem to want to "forward declare" the *enumerators* of that `enum`. That's a different matter entirely, and it's not a thing you can do. Enumerators are supposed to be compile-time constants, which means the value of that constant needs to be visible when compiling it. Which means that the enumerator name needs to know what the constant is at all times.

You can however forward declare a bunch of global constant variables (`extern const int name;`) and define them in whichever source file you like. However, you lose all of the advantages of enumerators. These will not be constant expressions (outside of the file in which these variables are defined), and thus, the compiler will have to emit code that accesses actual memory to extract the value of the variable. Also, there will be no relationship between the "enumerators"; you can switch over them, but the compiler won't know that the value is expected to be one of the enumerators.

Alternatively, you can define your own enumerators and write a function which converts SQLite's enumerator values to your enumerators. If users of your code are not expecting to deal with SQLite directly, then the only reason to use SQLite's enumerators is *your* convenience, not that of your users. That is, if you're going to expose your users to SQLite's status codes, then you are making SQLite a part of your library's *interface*, and users of your library are therefore also users of SQLite *directly*. If you don't want that, then you should provide an opaque layer between SQLite and the user.

Indeed, you could pick enumerator values that are identical to the SQLite values, and use `static_asserts` in your code to make sure that SQLite won't change their enumerator values behind your back (FYI: they're not going to do that in a minor version release; that would break ABI compatibility and therefore every DLL/SO user of their library).

Comment: So looks like only way to decouple is to write a mapping function from the public enum to the "hidden" ones. Looks the best solution I can achieve. I was wondering I can use underlying_type, but it requires to be in the header too.